# In Linux, how to unzip RAR archive containing files with Chinese file names?

Tags: linux, rar, chinese

How to unrar a RAR archive containing files with Chinese file names?

When I try to do it in Ubuntu 11.10 using the default program Archive Manager, it complains it can't do with the Chinese file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the unrar util supplied by Rarlab themself? You'll find it here:
http://www.rarlabs.com/download.htm
Just type unrar x  to unrar it. As long as your file system and locale supports the chinese file names I can't see why it wouldn't be possible to unpack the archive.

Comment: I installed `unrar` using `apt-get install unrar`. And `unrar e archivewithchinesefilenames.rar` works. I'm not sure if this `unrar` is the official version by rarlabs.

Answer (score 0):

unrar them at the command line.

```
unrar e somefile.rar
```

This worked for me.